# Rounding a decimal number down

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, numbers

When we divide 5 by 2 we got a decimal number: 2.5

What I want is to divide INTEGER numbers by 2, not decimal numbers and not using the decimal divisor operator `/`.

Then I want to get this results for example: 5/2=2, 9/2=4, 11/2=5, etc...

Comment: So you want to always round down instead of up, or always round towards zero, or use bankers rounding, or what?

Comment: sounds like `Math.Round(5.0 / 2.0, MidpointRounding.ToEven)` would do the trick

Comment: Are you saying just 2.5 and below rounds down and 2.6 and above rounds up?  Or everthing from 2.0 to 2.9999999... rounds down to 2.0?

Comment: @RaphaelSmit That would work for this one exact example; it's unclear if that's what he wants in general.

Comment: @Servy true, after doing some more testing turns out it might not be the most effective method here.

Comment: @HansPassant Why wouldn't it be.  [There are many ways of defining how to handle the midpoint value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding), it appears the OP just isn't looking for one of the less common ones.  Rounding towards zero seems to be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: The reason for what you are getting in your updated question is that you are relying on integer. Convert them to Double and you would get the right output. Bear in mind that what VB.NET understands implicitely is not an exact science precisely, just tell it what has to understand by always converting numbers to double (or decimal or float) before doing an operation involving decimals

Comment: @varocarbas The code in the question actually shows him as using decimal division, not integer division.  That said, if he's not using the `deciaml` type, and instead is using floating point types, that could be the source of problems.

Comment: @Servy this is what I meant: the error derives from the fact that VB.NET does not perform the right interpretation to decimal/double/float. The best way to avoid problems is telling it exactly what you want.

Comment: What I want is to divide INTEGER numbers by 2, not decimals, and to get this results for example: 5\2=2, 9\2=4, 11\2=5, etc...

Comment: @Raphael Smit your solution works for what I need? I've tested it with some values and I think yes but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ElektroHacker Then you do want to truncate; you don't want to round.  That's a very different problem than what you asked for.

Comment: @Servy Then really I'm sorry for the mistake, I'm not a arithhmetic guru :P, if you please can show a solution? the truncate function of math class needs a decimal but I'm using integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform integer division in VB rather than decimal division you need to use the proper operator.

the `/` operator is for decimal division.  The `\` operator is for integer division.

```
1 / 2  'results in 0.5
1 \ 2 'result in 0
```

Comment: ofcourse I knew the divisor operators but when I've tried to "truncate" I get the rounded number that's why next I did is tried with the Math Class, but I've tested again now 'cause I seen your comment and now it worked fine, maybe I misspelled the divisor operator or something, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way is to use the negative of the round of the negative.

Comment: Sorry I did not understanded, you mean tu use negative digts? I've tried it but ca't get the desired result

Comment: @ElektroHacker Something like: `-round(-n)`

Answer (score 1):

System.Math.Truncate should do what you want.
e.g., int result = (int)Math.Truncate(9 / 2.0);

Comment: There's no need to call `Truncate`.  Casting to `int` will itself truncate the value.  Better still, you could just do integer division in the first place instead of going through all the effort of performing floating point division just to ignore the result.

Comment: @Servy: Yes - of course - not enough caffeine yet this morning.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 pretty easy ways to do this that come to my mind.

1. The `Math.Truncate()` function
2. Simply switch from the `/` symbol to the `\` symbol. This is pure integer division like you are seeking and will automatically truncate your answer to the last whole number.

I would recommend option 2 because I'm pretty sure it stops doing calculations once it gets to the last full integer rather than dealing with any decimals at all (past testing and seeing the first one to recognize it is at the end of the integer) while the `Math.Truncate` function does not. If anyone knows for sure, I would appreciate knowing.